# How to Batch Convert with FFmpeg 2 Pass?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, command-prompt

I'm converting webm to mp4 using FFmpeg.

My batch file is

```
cd "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\" && for %f in (*.webm) do ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\%~f" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 600K -pass 1 -acodec aac -b:a 128k "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\%~nf.mp4" && ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 600K -pass 2 -acodec aac -b:a 128k "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\%~nf.mp4"
```

It works for CRF and 1 Pass, but using 2 Pass it stops on the second pass and gives the error:

C:\Users\Matt\Desktop" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 600K -pass 2 -acodec aac -b:a 128k C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\video: Invalid argument

The first double quote is missing on the Path, and the filename "video 01.mp4" is cut off.

Comment: Are you certain that the `-i` parameter in the second pass is correct? The other two times you've used it, you've specified a file. In the last instance, it appears to be a directory - possibly the terminal `\"` is being interpreted as an escaped-`"`

Comment: @Magoo You're right, the second Path is missing %~f. That solved it, thanks.

Comment: 2-pass means that the output of the first pass is used as input for the second one, right?

Comment: @aschipfl I'm not sure now. On the wiki it shows the original source being used as the input for both passes. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass

Comment: Ah, I see. You should rather trust the documentation than me, I do not really know `ffmpeg`, it just appeared more logical to me the way I said, but the tool seems to work differently (I guess there is a temporary file somewhere holding the information gathered during the first pass). Sorry for confusing you!

Answer (score 2):

Your code could only work in cmd directly, in a batch you have to double the percent signs of the for variable.
There is no need for a one liner in a batch.
I hope this is more clear and works.

```
@Echo off
Pushd "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\"
for %%f in (*.webm) do (
  ffmpeg -y -i "%%~f" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 600K -pass 1 -acodec aac -b:a 128k -f mp4 NUL 
  ffmpeg -y -i "%%~nf_tmp.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 600K -pass 2 -acodec aac -b:a 128k "%%~nf.mp4"
)
PopD
Pause
```

Comment: Your file worked but it also crashed FFmpeg for some reason at the end, but it might be my videos. I'm also trying to copy paste the code into CMD without the .bat file. Do you see the mistake in my code for that?

Comment: @MattMcManis Well I'm no ffmpeg specialist, the parameter selection is up to you.

Comment: Does the %~nf_tmp.mp4 have to be used or can I use the same input file as -pass 1 %%~f for -pass 2?

Comment: Maybe you need an arg to overwrite the same file, I chose a different name for clarity.

Comment: @LotPings You could replace `"%%~nf_tmp.mp4"` with `-f mp4 NUL` because the first pass doesn't need to output an actual file, so it will potentially be faster. In the very rare cases I encode using two-passes I omit the audio in the first pass because it's unnecessary to encode it twice (you could replace `-acodec aac -b:a 128k` with `-an` to do that), but by omitting it some have claimed they get an error of some sort...not one that I've ever duplicated.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Would they please edit my answer to incorporate the suggested changes ;-) Or create an own answer.

Comment: @LotPings Sure. Edited.